# How to prevent Java reflection to access a custom Java package in a custom Android?

Tags: java, android, reflection, dalvik

Let us say I have a custom Android 4.3 with a custom java package xyz.java.

**My questions are:**

1. How to use **Java security manager** to prevent apps from using reflectoin to enumerate Java methods in my custom Java package xyz.java?
2. Where in Android source code should I put the Java security manager code (suggested in 1) to prevent apps from enumerating methods in my custom package xzy.java?

Comment: Android doesn't really use the SecurityManager classes for security. It's not really clear what thread you believe you're facing... each app runs in its own VM, so other apps won't be using reflection calls to examine yours.

Comment: I ended up changing the reflectoin code in Class.java to solve the problem but the code does not work. **Do you know how to print a message within Class.java so I can see it in the adb logcat to fix the code?**